# How can I limit two dates in an ExtJS DatePicker?

Tags: regex, extjs, datepicker, extjs4

I have a DatePicker in ExtJS4.  I only want to allow TWO dates for each month.  The 15th and last day (30/31/28/29 depending on month/year)

How can I disable every day in the picker but allow those two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `disabledDates` config option for `Ext.form.field.Date`

From API docs:

> disabledDates : String[] An array of "dates" to disable, as strings.
>   These strings will be used to build a dynamic regular expression so
>   they are very powerful. Some examples:
>
> ```
> // disable these exact dates:
> disabledDates: ["03/08/2003", "09/16/2003"]
> // disable these days for every year:
> disabledDates: ["03/08", "09/16"]
> // only match the beginning (useful if you are using short years):
> disabledDates: ["^03/08"]
> // disable every day in March 2006:
> disabledDates: ["03/../2006"]
> // disable every day in every March:
> disabledDates: ["^03"]
> ```
>
> Note that the format of the dates included in the array should exactly
>   match the format config. In order to support regular expressions, if
>   you are using a date format that has "." in it, you will have to
>   escape the dot when restricting dates. For example: ["03\.08\.03"].

Comment: That's got me on the right track but I can't figure out the regex for allowing all 15th's and all `last day of month`.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's the hard par actually, which makes me wish there was a similar `allowedDates` option. Disabling days 1-14 and 16-27 is easily, if clumsily, done by just listing them. The trouble is with the last day of month.

Comment: You may determine the last day of the month subtracting 1 from the first day of the second month.

Comment: @Thevs: you got regex for that? ;)

Comment: Can't you preprocess this? ;)

Comment: how to disable in between dates?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Get the last date of the month. If in Feb 2012, lastDate is 29.
var lastDate = Ext.Date.getDaysInMonth(new Date());
//15th 
var middleDate = 15;

//Construct regular expression
var disabledArray=[];
var today = Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y');
var dateReg = /(\d{2}\/)\d{2}(\/\d{4})/;
disabledArray.push(today.replace(dateReg, '$1' + middleDate + '$2'));
disabledArray.push(today.replace(dateReg, '$1' + lastDate + '$2'));

//Something like "^(?!02/15/2012|02/29/2012).*$" including the two days allowed.
var disabledReg = '^(?!' + disabledArray.join('|') + ').*$';

//Apply the regular expression to date field
var dateField = new Ext.form.field.Date({
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    disabledDates: [disabledReg]
});
```